# Can a nondeterminstic algorithm preserve privacy?

Tags: cryptography

How can we define $\epsilon$-*differential privacy* for non-deterministic algorithms?

Comment: You may want to try crypto.stackexchange.com/ if no answer is given here

Comment: One line Questions may not provide Readers enough context to appreciate your interest in the information sought.  A [link to a definition of $\epsilon$-differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy#%CE%B5-differential_privacy) and thoughts on what prevents its application to [non-deterministic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm) would improve your chances of a useful response.   In most cases randomized algorithms would be considered non-deterministic, so articulating the distinction is a place to start.